# How can I create group column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to divide data each 2unit raw using pandas

for example

df_A: raw data

| data1 | data2 | data3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 13.3 | 983 |
| 13 | 33.4 | 124 |
| 24 | 62.3 | 574 |
| 25 | 78.5 | 554 |
| 63 | 93.3 | 982 |
| 29 | 43.3 | 123 |
| 53 | 62.6 | 364 |
| 83 | 74.3 | 453 |
| 21 | 83.0 | 165 |
| 93 | 23.4 | 433 |

df_B :result data

| group | data1 | data2 | data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 23 | 13.3 | 983 |
| 0 | 13 | 33.4 | 124 |
| 1 | 24 | 62.3 | 574 |
| 1 | 25 | 78.5 | 554 |
| 2 | 63 | 93.3 | 982 |
| 2 | 29 | 43.3 | 123 |
| 3 | 53 | 62.6 | 364 |
| 3 | 83 | 74.3 | 453 |
| 4 | 21 | 83.0 | 165 |
| 4 | 93 | 23.4 | 433 |

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df["group"] = df.index // 2
```

Or:

```py
df["group"] = np.arange(len(df)) // 2
```

---

This creates `"group"` column:

```py
   data1  data2  data3  group
0     23   13.3    983      0
1     13   33.4    124      0
2     24   62.3    574      1
3     25   78.5    554      1
4     63   93.3    982      2
5     29   43.3    123      2
6     53   62.6    364      3
7     83   74.3    453      3
8     21   83.0    165      4
9     93   23.4    433      4
```